# Passing URI list to ACTION_QUICK_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

Ref: [ACTION_QUICK_VIEW_DOCUMENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_QUICK_VIEW)

It says in the docs that ACTION_QUICK_VIEW should be able to take a Uri list via ClipData so that multiple items can be displayed, which I've tried - but the image view ends up just being completely "black", as if there's no images loading in.

Setting just the "intent.data" with a single Uri works just fine, it's just when the ClipData is added that it blanks out.

I'm two days new to Kotlin/Android, so sorry if my approach here is completely wrong xD

```
var uriArray = ArrayList<Uri>()
/*
some loop to populate uriArray with image URLs
eg: */
uriArray.add("https://example.com/image1.jpg".toUri())
uriArray.add("https://example.com/image2.jpg".toUri())
uriArray.add("https://example.com/image3.jpg".toUri())

val clipData: ClipData? = null
uriArray.forEach {
    var item = ClipData.Item(it)
    if (clipData == null) {
        ClipData("URIs", arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_URILIST), item)
    }
    else {
        clipData!!.addItem(item)
    }
}

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_QUICK_VIEW)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
intent.clipData = clipData
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INDEX, 2)  /* just for testing, should put us at image index 2 */

startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: See if there are any messages in Logcat when you fire off this  `Intent`. It's possible that there are limits on the `ClipData` scenario. For example, you are asking to view Web content -- perhaps the multiple-`Uri` feature only works for local content.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  There doesn't seem to be any output on Logcat at all when the Intent is fired, perhaps because the Intent is outside the my app that it can't monitor it?  I also tried with local resources bundled in the app - but same results as the web source.

Comment: "because the Intent is outside the my app that it can't monitor it?" -- if you are using Android Studio, make sure that you are not filtering Logcat to be only messages from your app.

Comment: Ahh, I completely missed that - I switched it over to filter none.
There doesn't really seem to be any errors,  it logs:  `019-07-06 15:20:33.086 928-939/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.QUICK_VIEW flg=0x10000001 cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/com.google.android.apps.viewer.ProjectorActivity clip={text/uri-list U:https://example.com/image.jpg ...} (has extras)} from uid 10197`  
The only thing I can guess is that the "text/uri-list U:" being passed to it isn't what it wants.  When I use  "intent.data", the output is a bit different with  `dat=` being the URL.

Comment: That should be correct, given the docs. What devices/emulators have you been testing on? There are no bugs filed for this action against Android proper, but this might be an environment-specific issue.

Comment: Currently testing on two physical devices - Pixel XL (api28) and a Samsung SM-T377V (api25), both seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem like EXTRA_INDEX is working either.  No matter the index I give it, URL Logcat shows is always the one at 0.